# .Net 6 Auth0 Trying to add user to Auth0 with errors

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, auth0

Im struggeling, I've never used Auth0 before and trying to add consultants to the Auth, but Im getting error after error

This is the errors/console:
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

This is the code

```
[HttpPost("post-consultant")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ConsultantUserPostDTO>> RegisterNewConsultant([FromBody] ConsultantUserPostDTO consultantUserDTO)
{
    try
    {
        var newUser = await _userService.CreateNewUserConsultant(
            consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Username,
            consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Email,
            consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Password
        );

        var newConsultant = await _consultantService.CreateNewConsultant(
            newUser.Id.ToString(),
            consultantUserDTO.ConsultantPostDTO.Name,
            consultantUserDTO.ConsultantPostDTO.Bio,
            consultantUserDTO.ConsultantPostDTO.TechtypeIdConsultant,
            consultantUserDTO.ConsultantPostDTO.RegionIdConsultant
        );

        string auth0Domain = "https://speedview.eu.auth0.com";
        string auth0ManagementApiToken = await _auth0Service.GetManagementApiTokenAsync();

        // Construct the Auth0 Management API URL
        using (var auth0Client = new AuthenticationApiClient("https://speedview.eu.auth0.com"))
        {
            // Create the ManagementApiClient object with the correct Auth0 domain

            Console.WriteLine("Will it work?");
            string auth0ManagementApiUrl2 = "https://speedview.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/users";
            Console.WriteLine("Maybe?");
            var managementApiClient = new ManagementApiClient(auth0ManagementApiUrl2, auth0ManagementApiToken);
            Console.WriteLine("Closer!");

            // Create a new user in Auth0
            var userCreateRequest = new UserCreateRequest
            {
                Connection = "Username-Password-Authentication",
                UserName = consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Username,
                Email = consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Email,
                Password = consultantUserDTO.UserPostDTO.Password,
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Getting hot!");
            // Create the user in Auth0
            var createdUser = await managementApiClient.Users.CreateAsync(userCreateRequest);

            Console.WriteLine("BOILING!");

            return Ok(createdUser);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while processing your request.");
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to add a new user/consultant so that they can log in to our application.

Comment: Hi @chrida, did you debug your code to check which line makes such error? For such error, pls be sure that the URI you are providing is correctly formatted. It should include the protocol and a valid hostname.
Double-check for any typos or special characters that might be causing the parsing error.

Comment: according to this link: https://auth0.github.io/auth0.net/api/Auth0.ManagementApi.ManagementApiClient.html , ManagementApiClient takes token as first argument.  Looks like you have URL first, so maybe use:  var managementApiClient = new ManagementApiClient(auth0ManagementApiToken, auth0ManagementApiUrl2);